# Error connecting to MS SQL SERVER in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-ctools

I m using Pentaho v5.2. When i tried to connect to sql server i m end with below error. I had downloaded and placed required driver **sqljdbc4-2.0** jar in `pdi-ce-5.2.0.0-209\data-integration\lib`. Please help me as I'm new to Pentaho.

```
Error connecting to database [mssqlserverconn] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
Login failed for user 'Lenovo-PC\RamaKrishna'.


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
Login failed for user 'Lenovo-PC\RamaKrishna'.
```

Comment: It says login failed. You sure your user have the access to login to sqlserver? with correct username password?

Comment: yes..i gave corrext username and password

Comment: You might be using `Integrated Security`, which basically takes your computer's user domain and your logged-in username instead of the username you might really need in order to connent. See suggested answer

Answer (score 1):

From the error message you're being thrown, it's an authentication issue.
It looks like you are trying to use your username from your laptop domain - is that what you want? Does the the server accept this user name (`Lenovo-PC\RamaKrishna`)?

You may have been using integrated security, which basically overrides whatever you set as the username in the text-box and uses your Windows username instead.

See below:
[image: MS SQL CONNECTION NATIVE]